# save xml object so that elements are in sorted order in saved xml file

Tags: java, xml, sorting

I am saving a xml document object and it is saved in a xml file as shown below .

```
<author name="tom" book="Fun-II"/>
<author name="jack" book="Live-I"/>
<author name="pete" book="Code-I"/>
<author name="jack" book="Live-II"/>
<author name="pete" book="Code-II"/>
<author name="tom" book="Fun-I"/>
```

instead i want to sort the content in  document object so that when i persist the object  it is saved by grouping authors then book name as below:

```
<author name="jack" book="Live-I"/>
<author name="jack" book="Live-II"/>
<author name="pete" book="Code-I"/>
<author name="pete" book="Code-II"/>
<author name="tom" book="Fun-I"/>
<author name="tom" book="Fun-II"/>
```

I use apache xml beans..any ideas on how to achieve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML has no sorting order, you could transform XML by using XSLT
Something like that:

```
<xsl:for-each select="author" order-by="+ name">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@book"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See also [Sorting in XSLT](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html) for furhter ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As stacker already mentioned, plain xml documents are never (usually?) not sorted or sortable. To have sorted xml documents, you could either sort the model before serializing it or create/use an external sorter to process existing xml documents.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted that the element

```
<author name="pete" book="Code-I"/>
```

Is identical to:

```
<author book="Code-I" name="pete"/>
```

Attribute nodes, unlike text nodes and element nodes have no ordering. Thus for the purposes of XML, you have to tell it on which attribute it should sort.